# redundant numbers in sentence

Tags: numbers

Is this sentence correct? Thank you

During 2015 and 2014, there were four and four employees, respectively, whose account balances exceeded a month’s salary.

Comment: It's correct, but you'd never say that: "**During both 2015 and 2014** there were four employees whose account balances exceeded a month's salary."

Comment: *In each of the years 2014 and 2015, there were four employees whose account balances....*

Comment: That fails to convey that they were four distinct sets of employees, though, but getting all the details in place would be kind of tortured.

Comment: Can the author give more context? What did the author want to express?

Comment: Are we talking about the same four employees?

Answer (score 1):

While technically comprehensible, that is an awkward construct your reader will probably need to scan more than once.

If we're talking about the same employees in both years, it would be better to rephrase the sentence:

**"During both 2015 and 2014, there were four employees whose account balances exceeded a month’s salary."**

If the employees or the numbers were different, it would scan more easily to split the two associations:

**"During 2015 there were six employees whose account balances exceeded a month’s salary.  During 2014, there were three."**

Your exact wording would obviously depend on what exactly you were trying to say.  (I think it might be somewhat telling that I was uncertain which possible interpretation of the numbers you had intended.)